# Openstack project quota modification using REST API

Tags: php, openstack

I am trying to add the limits for a newly created projet. I am using php for 
[Listing limits](http://developer.openstack.org/api-ref-blockstorage-v2.html#os-limits-v2%22Openstack%20REST%20API%20V2%22)
of a given project. But I am not able to create limits for newly created project. I looked at this [Stakoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19396480/openstack-modify-all-projects-quotas%22Stack%20overflow%20question%22). Here they are mentioning to edit the nova.conf file for a project. But I do not have any idea how to create and assign new limits for a project.

Also [here](http://developer.openstack.org/api-ref-blockstorage-v2.html#os-quota-sets-v2%22here%22) they are mentioning about quota for server. But I need managing quota for a project using openstck REST API.

Please help.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need is this: http://developer.openstack.org/api-ref-compute-v2.1.html#os-quota-sets-v2.1

For Nova API v2, refer to this: http://developer.openstack.org/api-ref-compute-v2-ext.html#os-quota-sets

Note, project has quota for each service individually, unfortunately some services don't support change quota via REST API (for i.e. Ceilometer), modify configuration file is the only way for those services.

Comment: Thank you bro. Thats what I needed.

Comment: One problem, my nova end point supports only v2.0 . But this service is avilable in v2.1 . Is there any way I can use this serveice, please suggest.

My identity node supports all lates version. But this compute service is the only problem.

Comment: OpenStack API Reference only has master release, which means the latest one, for old one, I have found this: http://developer.openstack.org/api-ref-compute-v2-ext.html#os-quota-sets

Comment: Thank you bro. Its perfectly working with v2. How I missed that. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

One of the easiest ways to find the openstack API you need is by using the CLI. Find the command you need and run it with the '--debug' flag. This will dump the API calls to the console, and you can work out what you need from there.

In you case, have a look at this CLI command:
http://docs.openstack.org/cli-reference/content/novaclient_commands.html#novaclient_subcommand_quota-update